# Using South migrations with Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-south

I have successfully synced my database using south on the local server. I am having problems using south in Heroku.  When I run

```
git add app/migrations/*

git commit -m 'adding new migrations'

heroku run python manage.py migrate app
```

I am getting a DatabaseError. Relation field already exists.

Any ideas why this isn't working? Also, do I need to run migrations locally and on the production environment each time one of my models change?  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems you already have the fields in your database for that app. try faking the migrations by  running

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate app --fake
```

Comment: Thank you. So for future reference, will I have to run the migrations on the local and production(Heroku) environment next time?

Answer (score 1):

do this on Heroku:

heroku run python manage.py migrate YOUR_APP_NAME 0001 --fake

then

heroku run python manage.py migrate YOUR_APP

that solved it for me. Just running migrate would give errors as for some reason south would try to run the initial migration as well. So I faked that one, and running the first actual migration (0002) worked fine after.